# SOQL to find whether user's role is part of the public group

Tags: soql, role-hierarchy, public-group

I have few public groups where I have only roles added. Is there any way to identify whether the current user is part of the group by taking current user's role and then comparing with the roles added in the  group?

I would like to build a SOQL to check whether my current user is part of the group, but with below SOQL it is returning always false -

```
SELECT GroupId,UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId =: <-----> AND UserOrGroupId =: <---->
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Role is mapped in user record so retrieve `UserRoleId` from User

In the `Group` object , `RelatedId` field stores following types of values:

- Role
- RoleAndSubordinates

Though `Group` can have other `Type` as follows which doesn't have `RelatedId`

- Organization
- Queue
- Regular

So, final query will be like this

```
SELECT Id,Name,DeveloperName,RelatedId,Type FROM Group 
WHERE RelatedId IN 
     (SELECT UserRoleId FROM User WHERE Id = <UserId>) 
AND Type = 'Role'
```

Also, refer [Fetch public groups for a user via Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000211729&type=1) for all types of complex scenarios.

Here is an example from my DE

[image: user group]

SOQL and results

[image: SOQL]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Exactly what I was looking for.